# Suffix Tree and Longest Repeated Substring issue

Tags: algorithm, suffix-tree

When running the algorithm on the string '`AEKEAAEKEAAEKEA$`' looking for the longest substring with at least 3 occurences all the nodes in the suffix tree have maximum 2 branches, how can that be?

The correct result should be the substring '`AEKEA`'.

You can easily see the tree in the  [online suffix tree builder](http://www.allisons.org/ll/AlgDS/Tree/Suffix/)

I just followed the Wikipedi description:

> "The problem of finding the longest substring with at least k
>   occurrences can be found by first preprocessing the tree to count the
>   number of leaf descendants for each internal node, and then finding
>   the deepest node with at least k descendants"

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that website is correct. When I run 'AEKEAAEKEAAEKEA' through my [suffix tree](http://code.google.com/p/java-algorithms-implementation/source/browse/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/data_structures/SuffixTree.java), I get the following tree.

```
└── (0)
    ├── (27) $
    ├── (6) A
    │   ├── (26) $
    │   ├── (16) AEKEA
    │   │   ├── (17) $
    │   │   └── (7) AEKEA$
    │   └── (18) EKEA
    │       ├── (19) $
    │       └── (8) AEKEA
    │           ├── (9) $
    │           └── (1) AEKEA$
    ├── (4) E
    │   ├── (24) A
    │   │   ├── (25) $
    │   │   └── (14) AEKEA
    │   │       ├── (15) $
    │   │       └── (5) AEKEA$
    │   └── (20) KEA
    │       ├── (21) $
    │       └── (10) AEKEA
    │           ├── (11) $
    │           └── (2) AEKEA$
    └── (22) KEA
        ├── (23) $
        └── (12) AEKEA
            ├── (13) $
            └── (3) AEKEA$
```

As you can see from this branch, you've found your longest substring with 3 occurences.

```
└── (0)
    ├── (27) $
    ├── (6) A
    │   ├── (26) $
    │   ├── (16) AEKEA
    │   │   ├── (17) $
    │   │   └── (7) AEKEA$
    │   └── (18) EKEA
    │       ├── (19) $
    │       └── (8) AEKEA
    │           ├── (9) $
    │           └── (1) AEKEA$
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm a little confused, in your tree too the max number of branches of each node is 2.

Comment: Node 0 has 4 branches and node 6 has 3 branches.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are right, but node 0 means "" and node6 means "A" and  there's no node that means "AEKEA" and has more than 2 branches

Comment: I think I got it! is said "leaf descendants" (not only the direct ones) and node 18 has 3 leaf descendants, you can verfiy this with the 'A' substring (6 occurrences): it has leaf decendants 27,26,17,7,19,9,1  Thanks for the help!